# C# sort a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting

I need to sort a string array like below.

```
<MP:F> SG10.01,"SG1 ANTA H 2300 MHz Mod",#.##," dB",LIM,23.00,34.00
<DATA> GEN_FREQ,2300e6,,MESSAGE,"Action: Connect the external PM power sensor to ANT A via N->7/16 adapter.",,DELAY,1000,,PICTURE,ANTA_PM.JPG
<MP:F> SG10.02,"SG1 to ANTA H 2302.5 MHz Mod",#.##," dB",LIM,23.00,34.00<DATA> GEN_FREQ,2302.5e6
<MP:F> SG10.03,"SG1 to ANTA H 2305.0 MHz Mod",#.##," dB",LIM,23.00,34.00<DATA> GEN_FREQ,2305.0e6
<MP:F> SG10.04,"SG1 to ANTA H 2380 MHz Mod",#.##," dB",LIM,23.00,34.00<DATA> GEN_FREQ,2380e6
<MP:F> SG10.05,"SG1 to ANTA H 2385 MHz Mod",#.##," dB",LIM,23.00,34.00<DATA> GEN_FREQ,2385e6
<MP:F> SG10.06,"SG1 to ANTA H 2390 MHz Mod",#.##," dB",LIM,23.00,34.00<DATA> GEN_FREQ,2390e6
<MP:F> SG10.07,"SG1 to ANTA H 2392.5 MHz Mod",#.##," dB",LIM,23.00,34.00<DATA> GEN_FREQ,2392.5e6
```

The sort follow the number of the frequency point and when i finish the sort, i will rearrang the index number?

How could i do?

Comment: I want to use the regular expression to find all the frequency point form the date and compare the frequency point then array each line follow the frequency point.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. You should show what you have tried so far to demonstrate that you have put some effort in this.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following:

- Parse each line into a corresponding data structure (struct or object to your liking)
- Insert each object into a `List<T>`
- Order the list using LINQ on the wanted field
- Output the values of the ordered to the array

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a routine to [parse from each record the desired sort creteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760197/string-parsing-in-c-sharp) (frequency point),
2. Create a [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) where you get the parsed **frequency point** on one hand and the entire strign on the other,
3. [Sort the Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-sharp-dictionary-by-value) according to the GEN_FREQ and rearrange all string together in the new order.

Comment: Got you some links for each step, take alook at them.