# Simple C# Tokenizer Using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm looking to tokenize really simple strings,but struggling to get the right Regex.

The strings might look like this:

```
string1 = "{[Surname]}, some text... {[FirstName]}"

string2 = "{Item}foo.{Item2}bar"
```

And I want to extract the tokens in the curly braces (so string1 gets `"{[Surname]}","{[FirstName]}"` and string2 gets `"{Item}"` and `"{Item2}"`)

So basically, there's two different token types I want to extract: {[Foo]} and {Bar}.

this question is quite good, but I can't get the regex right: 
[poor mans lexer for c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673113/poor-mans-lexer-for-c)
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

They're both good answers guys, thanks. Here's what I settled for in the end:

```
// DataToken = {[foo]}

// FieldToken = {Bar}

string pattern = @"(?<DataToken>\{\[\w+\]\})|(?<FieldToken>\{\w+\})";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(expression.ExpressionString, pattern,
RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

string fieldToken = string.Empty;
string dataToken = string.Empty;

foreach (Match m in matches)

{
    // note that EITHER fieldtoken OR DataToken will have a value in each loop
    fieldToken = m.Groups["FieldToken"].Value;
    dataToken = m.Groups["DataToken"].Value;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataToken))
    {
         // Do something
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldToken))
    {
         // Do something else
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless rules are very convoluted, that will be `(?<Token>\{\[.+?\]\})` for the first string and `(?<Token>\{.+?\})` for the second

Answer (score 1):

what about `(?<token>\{[^\}]*\})`