# Interpreter Arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm getting back into C#, and I've ran into a problem. I'm making an interpreter and I need to get strings and numbers. My first way was to use Regex, but I don't know how to use it that well.

Let's say I have this:

```
print "string 1" "string 2" 10
```

I need to get an array of the args/parameters:

```
{'string 1', 'string 2', '10'}
```

So if you can help I appreciate that.

Comment: Yes, but like I said, I want to split with spaces but If I have a string argument like "Hello There!" i want to get it with spaces.

Comment: You need a lexer.  Google has rather a large number of hits.  Arbitrarily, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673113/poor-mans-lexer-for-c-sharp) has been vetted for a long time.

Comment: An interpreter for what? Unless the "language" you want to interpret is very very primitive and very very limited, you would need to write some parser and/or lexer, which itself is not done easily/quickly. Yes, there are parser and lexer libraries out there, but if you still struggle with regular expressions, i believe (my apologies!) trying to utilize parser/lexer libraries will be even harder for you... :-(

Comment: Its a very simple language, nothing special.

Comment: "_nothing special_" Yeah, i heard that somewhere. Because it is "_not special_" it surely must be easy, or so i heard, too...

Comment: I've been working in Python for a year now, so its all different now.

Comment: Yeah, I made something like this in Python, it didn't need a lexer. I think I have an answer. I'll try to make it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is easily done with a [Lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). There are many lexers for C# (just do a quick google search), but if you want to learn, you can build one yourself.

You asked for the first step of a lexer work, called **tokenization**, that is correct splitting a string into smaller strings called *tokens*, taking into account things like single/double quotes, escape characters, variable expansions, and so on.

Tokenization is a simple task and you will find tons of ready-to-use libraries. Process is like that:

- scan the input string character by character
- mark boundaries for each token
- extract substrings (tokens) to an array

Comment: I'm doing that using a foreach loop but it keeps going on forever.

Comment: I've written Lexers before but this just won't work

Comment: Seems like you are iterating repeatedly over the same characters of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program from a console your arguments get passed into the `Main(string[] args)` where args contains your arguments

Comment: I'm making an Interpreter, anyway I appreciate your answer.